# Где размещается staging, testing environment в случае микросервисов работающих в облаке?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, devops, микросервисы

Допустим мы решили делать проект на Java, изначально с микросервисной архитектурой, работать он будет в AWS под управлением docker containers + kubernetes. Где в таком случае поднимать окружения для того чтобы:

- разработчики могли что-то проверить/потестить
- тестировщики могли полноценное тестирование проводить

Тоже в облаке или локально?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Давайте разберём задачи.

1. Тестирование разрабов это проблема разрабов.
2. Тестирование тестировщиков это проблема devops.

Поскольку Вы рассматриваете задачу devops то поднимаете QA инстансы для тестировщиков. Поскольку мощности в облаке это деньги собственно как и локально, то решение задачи зависит от целевой функции зависящее в основном от производительность/деньги/доступ. И у каждой компании целевая функция строится по разному. Так что готовьтесь к закрытию вопроса поскольку однозначный ответ получить проблематично.